# Terraform deploy different resource for enviroment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm new on Terraform so I'm sure it is a easy question.

I'm trying to deploy into GCP using terraform.

I have 2 different enviroments both on same GCP project:

- nonlive
- live

I have alerts for each enviroment so that is what I intend to create:

If I deploy into an enviroment then Terraform must create/update resources for this enviromet but don't update resources for rest of enviroments.

I'm trying to user modules and conditions, it's similar to this:

```
module "enviroment_live" {
  source = "./live"
  module_create = (var.environment=="live")
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy_live" {
  count = var.module_create  ? 1 : 0
  display_name = "Alert CPU LPProxy Live"
```

Problem:

When I deploy on live enviroment Terraform delete alerts for nonlive enviroment and vice versa.

Is it possible to update resources of one enviroment without deleting those of the other?

Regards

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you could probably try using Terraform workspaces if this is not a large-scale production environment: https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces.

Comment: > Is it possible to update resources of one environment without deleting those of the other? > You might need to have separate terraform state files for different environments. That can be achieved in many ways, and using 'workspaces' - is one of the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marko E suggested solution was to use workspaces:

[Terraform workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces)

The steps must be:

1. Create a workspace for each enviroment.
2. On deploy (CI/CD) select workspace befor plan/apply:

   terraform workspace select $ENVIROMENT
3. Use conditions (as I explained before) to create/configure the resource.